# Ansible find module with data from dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, ansible, find

I'm having a problem getting the data I want from invoking the ansible find module  while iterating over a dictionary. The goal is to get a list of files that can be cleaned up:

The dictionary looks like this:

```yaml
cleanUp:
  data1:
    paths: '/opt/some/path'
    patterns:
      - '^[0-9]{8}.*\.csv$'
      - '^.*[0-9]{8}\.jar$'
    age: '30d'
    type: file
    recurse: yes
    regex: yes
  data2:
    paths: '/opt/other/path'
    patterns: '^[0-9]{8}.*$'
    age: '60d'
    type: directory
    recurse: no
    regex: yes
```

My playbook is accessing the dictionary like this:

```yaml
    - name: find all files that are older than they should be
      find:
        paths: '{{item.value.paths}}'
        patterns: '{{item.value.patterns}}'
        age: '{{item.value.age}}'
        file_type: '{{item.value.type}}'
        recurse: '{{item.value.recurse}}'
        use_regex: '{{item.value.regex}}'
      register: oldFiles
      loop: "{{ cleanUp|dict2items }}"

    - name: add files to fileList
      set_fact:
        fileList: "{{ fileList + [item.path]}}"
      loop: "{{ oldFiles.files }}"

    - name: print Files to be deleted
      debug:
        var=fileList
```

The 2nd and third tasks above fail, but I think it shows what I'm trying to do I've tried many different changes and searches and am stuck.

When I throw in the following debug, it shows all the data I want, but I haven't been able to figure out how to use it:

```yaml
    - name: print oldFiles
      debug:
        msg: "{{oldFiles}}"
```

This is what the output looks like:

```
ok: [uat-host-01] => 
  msg:
    changed: false
    msg: All items completed
    results:
    - ansible_loop_var: item
      changed: false
      examined: 1526
      failed: false
      files:
      - atime: 1602241325.6995838
        ctime: 1602241322.1505592
        dev: 51713
        gid: 1001
        gr_name: username
        inode: 254462789
        isblk: false
        ischr: false
        isdir: false
        isfifo: false
        isgid: false
        islnk: false
        isreg: true
        issock: false
        isuid: false
        mode: '0644'
        mtime: 1602241322.1505592
        nlink: 1
        path: /opt/some/path/some.csv
        pw_name: user
        rgrp: true
        roth: true
        rusr: true
        size: 210721
        uid: 1001
        wgrp: false
        woth: false
        wusr: true
        xgrp: false
        xoth: false
        xusr: false
      - atime: 1602500497.3135107
        ctime: 1602500493.8174858
        dev: 51713
        gid: 1001
        gr_name: username
        inode: 254462790
        isblk: false
        ischr: false
        isdir: false
        isfifo: false
        isgid: false
        islnk: false
        isreg: true
        issock: false
        isuid: false
        mode: '0644'
        mtime: 1602500493.8174858
        nlink: 1
        path: /opt/some/path/someother.jar
        pw_name: username
        rgrp: true
        roth: true
        rusr: true
        size: 2459535
        uid: 1001
        wgrp: false
        woth: false
        wusr: true
        xgrp: false
        xoth: false
        xusr: false
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want here is the json_query filter in order to aggregate all the results from the loop iterations.

First, the var `oldFiles` is going to have a list of the results from each iteration in the loop under subindex `oldFiles['results']` which is documented here: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#registering-variables-with-a-loop

Second, use the Ansible `json_query` filter (take note of the `jmespath` python dependency): https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter

I've provided an example below based on the information you provided.

```yaml
---
- name: example remove old files
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    cleanUp:
      data1:
        paths: '/var/cache/dnf'
        patterns:
          - '.*\.solvx$'
          - '^.*\.rpm$'
        age: '30d'
        type: file
        recurse: yes
        regex: yes
      data2:
        paths: '/var/cache/fwupd'
        patterns: '^.*\.xmlb$'
        age: '10d'
        type: file
        recurse: no
        regex: yes
  tasks:
    - name: find all files that are older than they should be
      find:
        paths: '{{item.value.paths}}'
        patterns: '{{item.value.patterns}}'
        age: '{{item.value.age}}'
        file_type: '{{item.value.type}}'
        recurse: '{{item.value.recurse}}'
        use_regex: '{{item.value.regex}}'
      register: oldFiles
      loop: "{{ cleanUp|dict2items }}"

    - name: set fact for file list
      set_fact:
        fileList: "{{ oldFiles|json_query('results[*].files') }}"

    - debug:
        var: fileList
```

Comment: `oldFiles | json_query('results[*].files')` could be simplified in `oldFiles.results | map(attribute='files')`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @zigarn:
I took your response and modified it to this, which gives me exactly what I needed (...just in case someone else is also puzzled by this syntax)

```
- name: add files to fileList
  no_log: true
  set_fact:
    fileList: "{{ oldFiles|json_query('results[*].files[*].path') }}"
```